# How can I change variable value in runtime in Postman test?

Tags: postman, postman-testcase

I'm trying to use postman for some basic API security tests and I have this URL:

```
http://example.com/api/v1/users/{{userID}}
```

{{userID}} is set to some user on site, and I want to set three tests that check if request is valid, if request has IDOR and if request has SQL injection.

This is the idea:

```
// userID is set to 20 ( valid user )

pm.test("Initial valid request", function () {
    pm.expect(pm.response.text()).to.include("Peter"); });

 *CHANGE THE VALUE OF {{userID}} to 30 to test for IDOR*
 * URL should be set to http://example.com/api/v1/users/30 *

pm.test("IDOR protection valid", function () {
    pm.expect(pm.response.text()).to.include("User not found."); });

 *CHANGE THE VALUE OF {{userID}} to 20'or'1 to test for SQL injection*
 * URL should be set to http://example.com/api/v1/users/20'or'1 * 

pm.test("SQL injection test", function () {
    pm.expect(pm.response.text()).to.include("You have an error"); });
```

My question is how do I change the values of {{userID}} so that next request uses changed value and not the one from environment variables.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the docs](https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/test-scripts/):

> Tests will execute after the request runs

So each test will run based on the one request. So doing something like the following in your test

```
pm.collectionVariables.set('userID', 'IDOR*') 
// or
pm.variables.set('userID', 'IDOR*')
```

Won't have the effect you're after as it doesn't make a request per test.

One potential way to solve this would be to have multiple requests, all of which have set the different variable values in the Pre-request Script. As an example, you might have a request that looks like this:
[image]

And then the related test:
[image]

Comment: Yeah, I tried all those variable changes but all failed, I guess making three requests with pre-req scripts set might be the only solution. Thanks for answering.